# GCM- display AlertDialog in GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android

Hy guys. I've implemented Google Cloud Messaging in my app,but i have a problem when i try to display the message received from the server to the user.
I've managed to display the message in a toast,but i would like to use an Alert Dialog.
This is my GCMBaseIntentService:

```
 public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public static final String SENDER_ID = "546677596418"; 

    public GCMIntentService() {
       super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.e("Registration", "Got an error!");
         Log.e("Registration", arg0.toString() + arg1.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(final Context arg0, final Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
        Log.i("Registration", arg1.getStringExtra("message"));


        Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.post(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                /*  String msg = arg1.getStringExtra("message");
                if(msg != null){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0)
                    .setTitle("New Notification")
                    .setMessage(msg)
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                    }).create().show();
                }
              */  
            }         
        });

    }
    }
```

the commented part is my attempt  to display an alert Dialog.I think the context is the problem,but i don't really know how to fix it.
It would be better if i use notifications for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've solved the problem using notifications.I guess this will have to do:)

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(final Context arg0, final Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
        Log.i("Registration", arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
        String message= arg1.getStringExtra("message");

      generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), message);

private  void generateNotification(Context context, String message)
        {



            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, BBCAndroid.class);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            mBuilder.setContentTitle("BBC Android")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);


            PendingIntent in = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, 0);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(in);

            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        }
```